# Как нарисовать пунктирной линией?

Tags: java, android

Рисую линию так:

```
p.setStrokeWidth(1);
canvas.drawLine(crX, crY, ceX, ceY, p);
```

Как задать ей пунктир?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для некоторых эффектов с линиями в Android есть класс `PathEffect`. В частности он позволяет скруглять углы ломаных, делать линию не идеально ровной, рисовать пунктиром и другое.

Для того, чтобы начертить пунктирную линию потребуется класс `DashPathEffect`:

```
class DrawView extends View {

  Path path;
  Paint p1;
  Paint p2;

  public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    path = new Path();
    path.rLineTo(100, 300);

    p1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p1.setStrokeWidth(7);

    p2 = new Paint(p1);
    p2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    p2.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 30, 10}, 0));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);

    canvas.translate(250, 0);
    canvas.drawPath(path, p2);
  }
}
```

Здесь значения массива вещественных чисел в аргументе класса `DashPathEffect` - 30 длина пунктира, 10 - расстояние между пунктирами.
Класс работает с любыми объектами канвы, которые рисуют линии (прямоугольник, круг и тд)

[Узнать больше](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/348-urok-151-risovanie-patheffect.html) про класс `PathEffect`.

Comment: Получилось! Благодарю!